# JSON запрос на HTTPS сервер на android

Tags: java, android, json, https

К сожалению, нигде не найду хорошего примера. Допустим, нужно сформировать окно логина. На сервер посылаются данные "login" и "pass", после чего, если пришел ответ, в котором "error": true, то осуществляется переход на след. страницу. Это мой первый такой опыт, более-менее разобрался с http, но, как оказалось, этих знаний не достаточно для работы с https сервером.

Comment: А в чем вопрос-проблема?

Comment: В том, как это реализовать

Comment: А что вы пытались сделать? Вы вот написали что c http получилось, а с https какие-то проблемы. Так что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Делал по данному примеру: http://dajver.blogspot.ru/2013/02/json.html
После того, как не было никакого результата, стал искать по интернетам и выяснил, что у htpps отличается.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JSONManager {
    String url ="http://";//твой урл
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    public static String KEY_code_operation = "code_operation";
    private Context mContext;
    public JSONManager(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public boolean putPhoneNumber(String phone_number) {
        phone_number=phone_number.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair(KEY_code_operation, "101"));//поля которые передаешь
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_number", phone_number));//поля которые передаешь
        Log.e("JSONManager", "?phone_number="+phone_number
                +"&"+KEY_code_operation+"="+"101"
                        );
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "POST", param);
        Log.e("json answer: ", json.toString());
        boolean success = false;
        try {//son answer:(12102): {"success":true,"message":"sended sms"}

            success = json.getBoolean("success");
            String message = json.getString("message");
                return success;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

JSONParser:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

        private static final long CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT = 20000;
        private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 20000;
        private static final int SO_TIMEOUT = 20000;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    private  String safelog(HttpEntity httpEntity){
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          try {
            httpEntity.writeTo(stream);
          }
         catch (  IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          try {
            return httpEntity.getContentType()+"\n"+URLDecoder.decode(stream.toString(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
            return httpEntity.getContentType()+"\n"+stream.toString();
        }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                //---------1-----content
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONN_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SO_TIMEOUT);

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
//              httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
//                          "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
//              httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
//              httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8));

                StringEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(entity);

//              httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"windows-1251"));
//              httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"iso-8859-1"));

                Log.e("JSONParser","httpPost:\n"+safelog(httpPost.getEntity()));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                //------1---------------
                //----2---json
//              JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
//              for (NameValuePair param:params)
//              jsonObj.put(param.getName(), param.getValue());
//              // Create the POST object and add the parameters
//              HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
//              StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
//              entity.setContentType("application/json");
//              httpPost.setEntity(entity);
//              HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
//              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, CONN_TIMEOUT);
//              HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, SO_TIMEOUT);
//              DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
//              
//              Log.e("JSONParser","httpPost:\n"+safelog(httpPost.getEntity()));
//              
//              HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                //---------2
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                is = httpEntity.getContent();



            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }else if(method == "PUT"){
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(url);
                httpPut.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPut);

                is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            }   else if(method == "DELETE"){

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(url);


                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpDelete);
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()  == 204)
                   return  jObj = new JSONObject("{\"success\":\"204 No Content\"}");
            }               


        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                    try {
                        return  jObj = new JSONObject("{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Time out Exception\"}");
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            jObj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
                jObj.put("videos",ja);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ:

```
JSONManager mJSONManager = new JSONManager(getApplicationContext());
boolean access = mJSONManager.putPhoneNumber("+35467698794");
if (access ){
   Log.e("","Успешная регистрация");
}
```

Comment: Приложение крашится. Что может быть не так?
http://rghost.ru/8r45Sb5Wd/image.png

Comment: @lirish что это? лог краша покажи